# Google Keyword Tool sample code in Flex or actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, soap, google-ads-api

I am a flex developer, well this time , client requirement has came to search the keyword in google adword,

go to the following link, if i enter some keyword here in the search box like

https://adwords.google.com/select/KeywordToolExternal

"dog training tips", so i get lots of results, i have to develop this same application in flex, which will fetch the data from this google's tool,

Does any one of you having any idea about how to get this data from flex, is there any flex or actionscript API available which will return me the data, that i'll filter according to ma requirement,

Thanx in advance

Ankur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware that there is any library available for actionscript so I think you're going to need to construct the SOAP calls manually. One possibility to make things easier would be to use one of the libraries and grab the SOAP that's being logged then insert your own values.

Comment: i think the various available api like php, java etc are available, i shd do the things from these api and get the data in to my flex appilcation, is that what u r saying Ewan??and Yes we have PHP development team, so they can do the things at their emd, and can return data to our flex end, n e ways, thanx ma frnd